# Setting position of cursor in Ace Editor

Tags: ace-editor, ui-ace

I have a use case where a user clicks a button to insert text at the current cursor position.
But after the text is inserted using `session.insert(cursorPosition, textToAdd)`, the position of cursor moves to the very first character.

I tried placing the cursor after the recently added text by using the following approach but it didn't work.

```
renderer.scrollCursorIntoView({
    row: cursorPosition.row,
    column: cursorPosition.column + param.length
}, 0.5)
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Basically, if a user keeps clicking the button, text to should be added at the current cursor position and then after the recently added text unless user places the cursor somewhere else explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

Here is your answer:

```
ace.edit('editor').moveCursorTo(lineNumber,colNumber);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q27ebeeq/130/

Just tested and it works exactly as expected!
It even scrolls the cursor into view automatically, although the console warns that this behaviour will change in future versions.

> Automatically scrolling cursor into view after selection change this
>   will be disabled in the next version set editor.$blockScrolling =
>   Infinity to disable this message

Hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: If you notice the value of the Ace Editor, it does not reflect the changes made to the value via Button. It shows the default value that was there at the start - *Default Text*

Comment: I see what you mean, but come on man, are you saying you can't figure that part out by yourself?

Comment: Anyway, your question was to insert the value and move the cursor there...????????????????

Comment: Thanks for your time buddy. I did mention that in the comment in the fiddle. :)

Comment: The problem isn't the solution I suggested, it's in your code, I'm trying to figure it out now

Answer (score 1):

When the user inserts text, you could use goToLine(), which takes in row and column as parameters and the cursor is set at that position.

```
editor.gotoLine(row, column);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this line `editor.moveCursorLineEnd()` after

```
session.insert(cursorPosition, textToAdd)
```

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q27ebeeq/141/)

Answer (score 0):

There is `editor.selection.moveTo(row, column)` but you do not need to use it after insert.
Selection moving to the beginning of the document indicates that something in your code is calling setValue on the editor. (e.g it may be a buggy react component recreating the editor) but that's hard to say for sure without seeing the page with the error

Comment: I am not calling the setValue after insert but I am assigning value of that to an angular Scope variable because if I don't do that, value of Ace Editor and Model Variable are not in Sync but cursor position issue is resolved.

Comment: then your angular component must be calling setValue, doing that can be slow.

Comment: If I am using editor.insert, why do I need to call setValue?

Here's the JS Fiddle - Here's the JS Fiddle for reference - https://jsfiddle.net/ashitvora/q27ebeeq/34/

Comment: I mean, someone is calling setValue, not that you need to call it, 

In your example https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace/blob/4c62a97e0adc60b7cde2be4caf902ac95c5c8c34/src/ui-ace.js#L273 is calling setValue, it needs to be changed to not call that unless the value is different.

Comment: Ok. But since it is a part of the library, what can be the solution for this except making a PR :)

Comment: there does not appear to be any good workaround, you could move insert call into setTimeout to not trigger the check at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace/blob/4c62a97e0adc60b7/src/ui-ace.js#L231 and filed.value updated automatically https://jsfiddle.net/q27ebeeq/96/.